# Orientation in Tab Bar Application

Tags: ios, youtube, screen-orientation

I have created a Tab Bar Application that I want to show in portrait all the time except when playing youtube Videos in fullscreen using a Web View in one of the View Controller of the application.

How can I do this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the project settings, select the Portrait,Landscape Left and Landscape Right device orientations.

In the TabBarController class, override the supportedInterfaceOrientation method. Refer to the code below.Copy and paste this code in your TabBarController

```
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
  return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

This makes sure that the Tab bar view always remains in portrait.

In the ViewController having the web view, implement the following version of supportedInterFaceOrientation method.

```
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight |   UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft;
}
```

This makes sure that the ViewController with web view can change to landscape orientation.

Note: Present the ViewController having web view modally. It should not be a tab in the TabBarController.